# Proof applying density.

Tags: real-analysis

8. (Exercise 1.2.8 in Lebl) Show that for any two real numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x < y$, we have an irrational number s such that $x < s < y$.
   Hint: Apply the density of $\mathbb Q$.

I'm just learning to write proofs and can't get anywhere.

Comment: I guess you mean rational?

Comment: No, the exercise asks for irrational number.... Should be the same?

Comment: That's weird, but just replace in my answer $\mathbb Q$ with $\mathbb R - \mathbb Q$

Comment: This has to be a duplicate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can assume that $x > 0$. Since $x < y$, $y - x > 0$. Then since both $1$ and $y -x$ are positive real numbers, there exists a natural number $q$ such that $(y - x)q > 1$ by the Archimedian property. By the same principle, the set $S = \{n \in \mathbb{N}: \frac{n}{q} \geq y\} \neq \emptyset$ hence there exists a smallest $m > 1$ (since $ y > (y - x) > \frac{1}{q}$ ) such that $x + \frac{1}{q} < y \leq \frac{m}{q} \implies \frac{m-1}{q} \in (x, y)$.

Since $\frac{y - \frac{m-1}{q}}{2} > 0$, by the Archimedian Property there exists $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{y - \frac{m-1}{q}}{2} > \frac{1}{n}$. Then we have $x < \frac{m -1}{q} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n} < \frac{m -1}{q} + \frac{\sqrt{4}}{n} < y$. Now check that $s = \frac{m -1}{q} + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{n}$ is an irrational number sitting in $(x, y)$.

Answer (score 3):

I'll assume that we've already shown that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. Now since $\frac{x}{\sqrt 2},\frac{y}{\sqrt 2} \in \mathbb R$ and $\frac{x}{\sqrt 2} < \frac{y}{\sqrt 2}$, we know by the density of $\mathbb Q$ that there exists some rational $q \in (\frac{x}{\sqrt 2},\frac{y}{\sqrt 2})$. Without loss of generality, notice that we may assume that $q$ is nonzero (for if $q = 0$, then we can just apply the same density argument to find some rational nonzero $q' \in (0, \frac{y}{\sqrt 2})$.

Now since $\frac{x}{\sqrt 2} < q < \frac{y}{\sqrt 2}$, observe that $x < q\sqrt 2 < y$. Notice that $q\sqrt 2$ is irrational (otherwise, if $q\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb Q$, then since $q$ is a nonzero rational number, we know that $\frac{q\sqrt 2}{q} = \sqrt{2}$ is also rational, a contradiction). Hence, we may take $s = q\sqrt 2$. $~~\blacksquare$

Comment: Thanks, now I'm goning to analyze this to really get the idea!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y$ be real numbers s.t. $x < y$. 
Define $ y-x=\epsilon >0$, then by the density of the rationals on the real line there exists a rational $$q \in (\frac{x+y}{2} - \frac{\epsilon}{4} , \frac{x+y}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{4})\subset (x,y)$$ therefore $x < q < y$ as needed